# Cmake file for C++/CUDA project

Tags: c++, cuda, cmake

I'm having trouble compiling my application using `cmake` and `make`. The source files of the project are organized as follows:

```
SOURCE/
  CMakeLists.txt
  myApp.cc
  include/
    classA.hh
    classB.hh
  src/
    classA.cc
    classB.cc
    classB.cu
```

My CMakeLists.txt file is as follows:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(myApp)

FIND_PACKAGE(VTK REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${VTK_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE(GDCM REQUIRED)
IF(GDCM_FOUND)
    INCLUDE(${GDCM_USE_FILE})
    SET(GDCM_LIBRARIES gdcmCommon vtkgdcm)
ELSE(GDCM_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find GDCM, did you set GDCM_DIR?")
ENDIF(GDCM_FOUND)

SET(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR="/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/")
FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA REQUIRED)
SET(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS ON)
SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30)

SET(LIB_TYPE SHARED)
SET(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(/lib/FFTW/INSTALL/lib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/lib/FFTW/INSTALL/include)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

FILE(GLOB headers  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hh)
FILE(GLOB sources  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cc)
FILE(GLOB cudafile ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cu)


CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(myApp myApp ${headers} ${sources} ${cudafile})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myApp ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${GDCM_LIBRARIES} fftw3)
```

When I try to compile the project using make (after successfully running cmake) I get:

```
nvcc fatal   : A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified
CMake Error at myApp_generated_classB.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  ../BUILD/CMakeFiles/myApp.dir/src/./myApp_generated_classB.cu.o
```

Is breaking up the source file of a class into .cc and .cu files problematic?

Comment: Is anything in the following question/answer applicable? [nvcc fatal: A single input file is required for a non-link phase when an outputfile is specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528107/nvcc-fatal-a-single-input-file-is-required-for-a-non-link-phase-when-an-outputf) applicable?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have already seen that post. I'm getting the same error but likely for a different reason. There the problem is whether "–" is used or "-". It appears the the error in my case stems from "../BUILD/CMakeFiles/myApp.dir/src/./myApp_generated_classB.cu.o".

Comment: What is the `nvcc` command being executed? For example, that question shows all the options being used to execute the compiler.

Comment: please post the output of `make VERBOSE=1` which shows how the compiler is invoked

Comment: @JamesAdkison, nvcc is the CUDA compiler. Please see http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/#axzz3q4yZJSVq.

Comment: @m.s., I ran make in the verbose mode, but it did not produce anything helpful other than one giant block of text. I also tried using .cuh and .cu instead of .hh and .cc+.cu but the problem persisted. The only interesting part in the make output was: Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in NoiseAddition_generated_Volume.cu.o.cmake:
  Syntax Warning in cmake code

Comment: I'm aware that it's the CUDA complier. The error seems to imply there may be an error in how the command is being invoked. Therefore, I thought it might be helpful to see all the options used to invoke the command...

Comment: you might have to run `make clean` prior to  `make verbose`. you could paste the output at pastebin.com and then link here; this might be problematic: `SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30)` try using a string: `SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30")` or `list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30)`

Comment: @JamesAdkison, my apologies. Perhaps doing what m.s. has suggested will help. I will post the output of make on pastebin.com and will link here.

Comment: @m.s., Thank you for the instructions. Here is the pastebin.com link: http://pastebin.com/KMXVR4bW

Comment: Have you perhaps tried with CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS off?  My concern specifically would be with "-DvtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT=1 ( vtkRenderingContextOpenGL )" and other similar options.  With the spaces in there, it is possible that nvcc is viewing them as extra source files.  You could try copying that entire command into the command line and removing the spaces from each of those (or removing the options altogether) to see if it will compile.

Comment: I'd go for the same as @SamuelAdamBlake; I am even not sure wether this is a valid `#define` for the host compiler (gcc). Where are these defines set?

Comment: @SamuelAdamBlake Thank you for your comment. Yes, I have already tried SET(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS OFF), but it didn't help. I will try running the entire command manually.

Comment: @m.s. Thank you. I'm going to run the modified command in the command line as suggested by SamuelAdamBlake to see what I get.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a comprehensive explanation of what exactly causes the problem stated in the question; nevertheless it solves the problem in a fairly satisfactory way.

**First**, apparently there is a conflict between using `FIND_PACKAGE(VTK)` (and hence FIND_PACKAGE(GDCM) which seems to require *VTK CMake files* for `vtkgdcm`) and `nvcc`. This has been recently [reported on Mantis](http://www.vtk.org/Bug/bug_relationship_graph.php?bug_id=15351&graph=dependency). To avoid this conflict, I use:

```
LINK_DIRECTORIES(   {VTK_Directory}/INSTALL/lib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES({VTK_Directory}/INSTALL/include/vtk-6.2)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(   {GDCM_Directory}/INSTALL/lib)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES({GDCM_Directory}/INSTALL/include/gdcm-2.4)
```

instead of,

```
FIND_PACKAGE(VTK REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(GDCM REQUIRED)
```

**Second**, as for the CUDA part of the project, I put everything into a `.cu` file and use `CUDA_COMPILE(cuda_o  myCUDAstudff.cu)` to create an object file. Then I use the native C++ compiler to create an executable as usual using `ADD_EXECUTABLE( ... ${cuda_o})`. Since I am using the native C++ compiler as opposed to nvcc, I need to include the following header files in my kernel (myCUDAstudff.cu) file:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
```

and also link to `libcudart` in `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES()`, for which I used the shared library. I couldn't figure out a way to do the same with libcudart_static.a though.

Alternatively, one can use `CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(... myCUDAstudff.cu)` instead of all the above steps (i.e., CUDA_COMPILE(), ADD_EXECUTABLE(),...).